# SSD or Hard Drive in a hot and humid environment

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Are SSDs less prone to failure than traditional hard drives in a more humid and hot environment?

Answer (score 6):

Going off [this](http://blog.dothill.com/tag/ssd) post then Yes

This is the explanation given:

> With no moving parts, SSDs are not
>   susceptible to the same shock and
>   vibration limitations that can damage
>   or degrade spinning disk drives. And
>   because air density does not affect
>   them (as with HDDs) they can operate
>   at higher altitudes. Additionally,
>   many SSDs are more tolerant of extreme
>   conditions such as dust or moisture
>   than traditional hard disk drives.

This is supported [Here](http://Some%20environments%20are%20too%20hostile%20for%20a%20drive%20with%20a%20spinning%20platter%20to%20survive%20for%20long.%20The%20mechanical%20drive%20is%20too%20susceptible%20to%20damage%20from%20moisture,%20dust,%20vibrations,%20shock,%20and%20extreme%20temperatures.%20In%20sharp%20contrast,%20the%20solid%20state%20hard%20drive%20will%20survive%20more%20easily%20in%20all%20of%20these%20environments.)

> Some environments are too hostile for
>   a drive with a spinning platter to
>   survive for long. The mechanical drive
>   is too susceptible to damage from
>   moisture, dust, vibrations, shock, and
>   extreme temperatures. In sharp
>   contrast, the solid state hard drive
>   will survive more easily in all of
>   these environments.